# How to hit enter in dialog box in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, sendkeys

I have an Excel macro that creates a .txt file, opens the Save As dialog box, and fills the file name out. However, I can't figure out how to hit the enter button on the Save As dialog box.

I have tried using SendKey's enter but it does not appear to work.

Here is the bottom of my macro right now.

```
myPath = some path that I have
file_loc = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(myPath, fileFilter:="Text Files 
(*.txt), *.txt")
wb.SaveAs Filename:=file_loc, FileFormat:=xlText
wb.Close
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You'd only uase `GetSaveAsFilename` if you want the user to enter the file name/path (in which case you wouldn't want to programmatically hit the Enter key). If you know the name/path, then just call the `SaveAs` method.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the answer ThunderFrame! I changed the end of my VBA code to the following and it worked!

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
file_loc = some path that I have
wb.SaveAs Filename:=file_loc, FileFormat:=xlText
wb.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Be sure to put the `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` to disable the popup "Are you sure you want to save this file?"

Comment: yes, `DisplayAlerts` helps. But store the *current* value of DisplayAlerts in a variable, then *restore* to that value. You'll find that safer in the event that other code has deliberately set DisplayAlerts to False, only for your code to explicitly restore it to `True` regardless of what it was at the start of the procedure.

Comment: If `file_loc` is only the path, won't you need to also specify the actual filename within the path?

Comment: @YowE3K Yes, that is true, but I have made a function within VBA that takes arguments that determine the file name that I input from Python! :)